# Sublime Text 2 Auto complete stopped working randomly

Tags: text

I was writing some HTML in Sublime Text 2 and I noticed that the auto complete feature was no longer working. Just so we're clear, I'm not referring to the dropdown menu that suggests elements but rather the tag completion. Normally what happens is if I were to type an opening tag all I'd have to do is type the beginning of the closing tag and it would auto complete the tag which obviously saved a lot of time but now it's not working for some reason. I do have package control installed along with quite a few extensions but I heard that this feature is actually built in. I deleted ST2 off my computer and re-downloaded it, and it still isn't working so I'm not sure what else to try.

Is this feature really a default feature in Sublime Text 2? If so, why wasn't it working when I re-installed Sublime Text 2?

I'm on a Mac and I'm running Yosemite.

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installed Sublime Text 3 and it works again.